# float left but div leave spaces in left

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I m trying to display list of images in div. for it I float it in left but after floating left it leave a lot of space and not display inline. can you help
snap shot is[image]

and my html code is

```
<div class="col75">
    <div class="col20">
        <img src="images/saari1.jpg" width="100%" />
    </div>
    <div class="col20">
        <img src="images/saari2.jpg" width="100%" />
    </div>
    <div class="col20">
        <img src="images/saari3.jpg" width="100%" />
    </div>
    <div class="col20">
        <img src="images/saari4.jpg" width="100%" />
    </div>
    <div class="col20">
        <img src="images/saari5.jpg" width="100%" />
    </div>
    <div class="col20">
        <img src="images/saari1.jpg" width="100%" />
    </div>
    <div class="col20">
        <img src="images/saari2.jpg" width="100%" />
    </div>
    <div class="col20">
        <img src="images/saari3.jpg" width="100%" />
    </div>
    <div class="col20">
        <img src="images/saari4.jpg" width="100%" />
    </div>
    <div class="col20">
        <img src="images/saari5.jpg" width="100%" />
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
```

and my css code is

```
.col20 {
    width: 17.5%;
    float: left;
    margin: 1%;
    border: 1px solid #f5f5f5;
    background: #e5e5e5;
}

.clear {
    clear:both;
}
```

Please help me how it solve it. I want my all images just like my first row inline

Comment: your HTML+CSS is just fine, http://jsbin.com/layoguruwope/1/edit shows nothing weird, spacing wise, so that weird whitespace in your image seems to come from something else that you've not mentioned in your post

Comment: i think you right.because when i use text in these div is work fine but not with image.  but i did not write any property for image. can you suggest me something

Comment: What do you mean 'display inline'? Are 5 images in one line or all images in one line?

Answer (score 0):

you may consider using `display:inline-block` instead of `float:left`
e.g.

```
.col75 {
    font-size:0px;
}
.col75 > div {
    display:inline-block;
    font-size:12px; // for expample
    vertical-align: baseline !important;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
       -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;        
    margin:1% 1% 0 0; // you may consider using px instead of %
    border:1px solid #f5f5f5; 
    background:#e5e5e5;
}
```

Comment: http://jsbin.com/zeqolelixuju/1/edit?html,css,js,output mmm? can you give a fiddle with your code? i used Mike's one...

Answer (score 0):

If you take a deep look you can see that not all images have same height and the problem is starting where is an image taller than the other ones : 
[image]

You can check [this fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/pzrxrddu/). On `.col20` i put a fixed height and `overflow:hidden;` and now everything is ok, but on some resolutions you could have some issues. 
Another way is to use [masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/), but according to this is unuseful.

If I were you, I would try to get all images on same sizes (width/height) ( from back-end, php or whatever ), or if is just some simple html, to slice all of them with same dimensions.